# wget and curl saving web page as gibberish (encrypted?)

Tags: wget, curl

When I download `https://www.wired.com/category/security/` using either `wget` or `curl`, the result is gibberish/encrypted.

Is it possible (and if so what is the correct way) to save that web page (unencrypted / plain HTML) from the command line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Executive summary:**

It seems like the downloaded file is compressed and you should decompress it.

**Detailed answer**

Running:

```
wget https://www.wired.com/category/security/
```

Result with a downloaded `index.html` file

Executing `file` command on the download file shows:

```
$ file index.html 
index.html: gzip compressed data, from Unix
```

Renaming the file and decompressing it turn it to be HTML document

```
$ mv index.html index.html.gz
$ gunzip index.html.gz 
$ file index.html
```

> index.html: HTML document, UTF-8 Unicode text, with very long lines, with overstriking

**Extra Info - why wget downloaded a compressed file?**

As explained in [How To Optimize Your Site With GZIP Compression](https://betterexplained.com/articles/how-to-optimize-your-site-with-gzip-compression/):

Instead of downloading a large text file, modern HTTP server/clients uses *Compressed HTTP Response* which reduce the size of the transfered files.

Comment: why would this page save compressed?

Comment: @JB0x2D1 - updated my answer

Comment: For me, `wget` saves plain HTML for the given URI. It is decompressed after transport. Do you possibly have some extra `wget` option set that causes it to save raw data?